# Loop only through one array from a multidimensional array (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a PHP multidimensional array, And I want to only loop through one array, for example array "a" or array "b" any suggestions please?

```
Array
(
    [59] => Array
        (
            ["a"] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 59
                            [user_id] => 122
                            [city_id] => 1
                            [country] => 2
                        )
                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 59
                            [user_id] => 123
                            [city_id] => 11
                            [country] => 3
                        )
                )
            ["b"] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 59
                            [user_id] => 124
                            [city_id] => 23
                            [country] => 1
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Thank you!

Comment: `foreach($myArray[59]['a'] as $value)` or `foreach($myArray[59]['b'] as $value)`

Comment: Please post it as an answer so I can accepte it as a solution to my question

Answer (score 3):

You need to access the correct index then:

```
foreach($myArray[59]['a'] as $value){

}
```

or

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($myArray[59]['a']); $i++){

// do something with $myArray[59]['a'][$i];
}
```